# Toggling overlayed sidebar in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap.

I have some text inputs to filter some data on my page.

How can I put these input fields in a hidden sidebar which is shown when I click on a toggler in the navbar? The sidebar should be overlayed and have full height.

I guess I can just use a `<div>` element with position absolute, height 100%, width 300px, top 0 and right 0, but I don't know how to toggle it from a button in the navbar. Besides, if the toggle button is in the right in the navbar, the sidebar will become overlayed on the button, so I cannot hide it again. The sidebar also has to be hidden if I click outside of the sidebar. I have looked through the bootstrap documentation, but there is no examples of this scenario.

Comment: Bootstrap does not support this, but you can use other JS plugins like http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/ - I'm using this and I'm satisfied. Pretty easy to use, if you have questions with that, I can help.

Comment: Yea bootstrap don't have sidebars, i tried using one that makshh provide but i had some problems with that one, you can check this framework and take sidebar only http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html but if you have `background-attachment: fixed;` somewhere in your website you will have problems. To be honest i didn't find great sidebar yet.

Comment: @NenadVracar slidebars is really great, I also was looking for great plugin for that and after little changes in CSS slidebars is fine. What problems did you have?

Comment: To be honest maybe there wasn't problem with slidebar maybe i was looking for that dimmed content or `pusher` animation and slidebar doesn't have it. I tried a lot of sidebars and every single one had some issue or it wasn't good enough for me. This one was pretty good http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can do this yourself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var open = false;

  var openSidebar = function() {
    $('.side-collapse').addClass('open-side');
    $('.navbar-toggle-side').addClass('open-side');
    $('#navbar-toggle-side').addClass('open-side');
    open = true;
  };

  var closeSidebar = function() {
    $('.side-collapse').removeClass('open-side');
    $('.navbar-toggle-side').removeClass('open-side');
    $('#navbar-toggle-side').removeClass('open-side');
    open = false;
  };

  $('.navbar-toggle-side, .nav-close').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var toggle = open ? closeSidebar : openSidebar;
    toggle();
  });

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.side-collapse').length) {
      closeSidebar();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle-side {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle-side:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle-side:focus,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle-side:active {
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #2480fe;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
  background: #2480fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse .navbar-nav > li:first-child a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:hover {
  background: #6B8AB5;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  border-right: 6px solid #2480fe;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .form-search,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .form-search:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .form-search:focus {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #2480fe;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 256px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse .nav-close i {
  line-height: 55px;
  right: 10px;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse {
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -256px;
  width: 256px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, .25, .005, 1.1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(1, .25, .005, 1.1);
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse.open-side {
  left: 0;
}
.alert.alert-success-alert {
  background: #2480fe;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.alert.alert-success-alert button.close {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse {
    top: 0px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle-side {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    width: 256px;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .side-collapse .nav-close i {
    line-height: 45px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle-side {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar.navbar-custom {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #6B8AB5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header" id="navbar-toggle-side">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-top" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-align-right"></i>

      </button>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle-side"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Yupppp</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-top">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-default side-collapse">
      <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse">
        <div class="nav-close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>

        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a> 
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a> 
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-search" placeholder="Search..." />
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-search" placeholder="Name..." />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-success-alert alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

    </button> <strong>Yup!</strong>

  </div>
  <dl> <dt>Yupppp...</dt>

    <dd>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de
      antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos
      del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por C icero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría
      de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32...</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl> <dt>Yupppp!...</dt>

    <dd>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de
      antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos
      del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por C icero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría
      de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32...</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl> <dt>Yupppp!!...</dt>

    <dd>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de
      antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos
      del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por C icero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría
      de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32...</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl> <dt>Yupppp...</dt>

    <dd>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de
      antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos
      del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por C icero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría
      de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32...</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl> <dt>Yupppp...</dt>

    <dd>Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio. Tiene sus raices en una pieza cl´sica de la literatura del Latin, que data del año 45 antes de Cristo, haciendo que este adquiera mas de 2000 años de
      antiguedad. Richard McClintock, un profesor de Latin de la Universidad de Hampden-Sydney en Virginia, encontró una de las palabras más oscuras de la lengua del latín, "consecteur", en un pasaje de Lorem Ipsum, y al seguir leyendo distintos textos
      del latín, descubrió la fuente indudable. Lorem Ipsum viene de las secciones 1.10.32 y 1.10.33 de "de Finnibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Los Extremos del Bien y El Mal) por C icero, escrito en el año 45 antes de Cristo. Este libro es un tratado de teoría
      de éticas, muy popular durante el Renacimiento. La primera linea del Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", viene de una linea en la sección 1.10.32...</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```